# Fix "Value is too long" in Directus field

Tags: field, directus

i have a CSV field in Directus and when i want to add one more tag it says "[VALUE_TOO_LONG] Value is too long.". I thought it was MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE so i added to .env file but nothing changed. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the difference between the String and Text types for the input field. String seems to have a maxlength of 255, so if you try to load a value larger than that it'll throw a "Value too long" error.

I fixed this by deleting my Input (String) field and re-creating it as an Input (Text) field.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had too many items in the table to change one by one.  Luckily, it was easy. As I was not able to find a feature to change the data type from string to text in directus, I just connected the database to pgadmin, and changed the data type for my field there.  There was no issue changing from string to text as there was no item in my table that contradicted the lengh limit, obviously.